# In SQL, is there something like: WHERE x = ANY_VALUE?

Tags: mysql, sql, parsing

In a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE x = 5;
```

is it possible to modify the WHERE condition so that SELECT looks for every value of x? Something like (wrong syntax):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE x = ANY_VALUE;
```

The reason behind this question is that I have to parse and modify some SQL queries through some C++ code I am writing. I know in this case I could just remove or comment the whole WHERE condition, but this is a simplification.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show what the actual query looks like where it is for some reason not possible to just simply remove the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: What's the simplification? I don't quite understand why you can't remove the WHERE condition altogether.

Comment: the purpose of select is to narrow down the rows to select ( that's where the name is coming from ). just leave it out..

Comment: @Darhuuk : I cannot remove the WHERE clause because there are other conditions to be tested.

Comment: @Pietro: So leave in the `WHERE`, but remove the comparison for the columns that shouldn't be checked...

Comment: what remove actually means is remove the x=5 or x= any_value and leave the other conditions. when you don't care what value is found in x, then just don't put a restriction(narrowing) on it in the where caluse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this, you normally would do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE x = SOME_VALUE OR 1 = 1;
```

SOME_VALUE is arbitrary, it can be anything matching the type of the column, because the `WHERE` clause will always be true because of the second part.

Comment: OR FALSE certainly not. This will always be FALSE and not help you

Comment: @Pietro: It doesn't help you AT ALL. You could just remove it, it has no effect whatsoever. Sample: `WHERE x = 5 OR FALSE`. It will return only rows with `x = 5`. It doesn't return any other rows as you specified in your question.

Comment: Besides: it isn't even understood by all DBMS, Oracle for example doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE x = x OR x IS NULL;
```

Comment: Or any other condition that evaluates to TRUE like `1=1` (Daniel Hilgarth) or simply `TRUE`

Comment: I agree and updated the post. And that is right, the other answers are good as well.

Answer (score 2):

While I think it's really the wrong way to go about it (just make the effort to remove the Where), how about where x = x?  It won't work if X is null (you'd have to use "x is null or x = x") but don't bother if you know x won't be null.

Answer (score 2):

You could just omit `WHERE` clause. :)

Comment: I cannot remove the WHERE clause because there are other conditions to be tested.

Comment: @Pietro: please update your question with a real example, because all proposed answers don't work in this scenario!

Answer (score 1):

You could make your query like this

```
DECLARE @VALUE as (type of x)
--SET @VALUE = ''
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (@VALUE IS NULL OR x = @VALUE);
```

and your parse would only have to replace
the: `--SET @VALUE = ''` line for one with the value you want, minus the comment, like: `SET @VALUE = 'abc'`

hope this helps

Comment: I substituted (type of x) with STRING, since that is the type of x, but I get a syntax error. What do you mean exactly?